# Hide element based on Meta title

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to hide an element based in a string in my sites Meta title.

This is the script im trying:

```
if($('title:contains("hide if this text shows")')){
   $( ".fusion-footer-widget-area .fusion-row" ).addClass( "hide" );
}
```

This ads a new class to my element which I have set `display:none` on.

But. This hides my element regardless on the text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add relevant HTML also

Comment: Relevant HTML? Its just an element in my footer. Then its just basic <title></title> tags where my text appears.

Comment: `my sites Meta title.` that's confusing, `<meta>`, `<title>` or `<a title=''>`

Comment: `if ( document.title.indexOf('hide if this text shows') !== -1)`

Comment: In addition, you can use the jquery function `.hide()` to hide. Or even the function `.toggle()` if the item will be shown/hidden often

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/)** property to check. `$('title:contains("hide if this text shows")')`  will be always true since it's a defined object , you should use `$('title:contains("hide if this text shows")').length`

```
if($('title:contains("hide if this text shows")').length){
   $( ".fusion-footer-widget-area .fusion-row" ).addClass( "hide" );
}
```

Or use **[`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)** which returns if the selector matches

```
if($('title').is(':contains("hide if this text shows")')){
   $( ".fusion-footer-widget-area .fusion-row" ).addClass( "hide" );
}
```